# Is there a client-side mock framework for RESTEasy?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jax-rs, resteasy

RESTEasy provides the [Server-side Mock Framework](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Server-side_Mock_Framework.html) for mocking server requests.  Is there an equivalent for unit testing the [client framework](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html)?

Is [InMemoryClientExecutor](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/core/executors/InMemoryClientExecutor.html) intended for this purpose?  I'm having trouble finding documentation and examples of how this class should be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `InMemoryClientExecutor` may be used for client-side mocking.  Looking in the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/2.3.4.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/client/core/executors/InMemoryClientExecutor.java#InMemoryClientExecutor), it internally uses the same classes as the server-side mock framework, namely, `MockHttpRequest` and `MockHttpResponse`.

`InMemoryClientExecutor` gives you the ability to override `createResponse` for mocking responses and also has a constructor which takes a `Dispatcher`, if you want to customize and intercept calls that way.

Here's a quick and dirty snippet leveraging the [client framework](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) example,

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.*;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.*;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.*;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.*;
import org.jboss.resteasy.mock.*;
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.*;
import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.*;

public class InMemoryClientExecutorExample {
    public interface SimpleClient {
       @GET
       @Path("basic")
       @Produces("text/plain")
       String getBasic();

       @PUT
       @Path("basic")
       @Consumes("text/plain")
       void putBasic(String body);

       @GET
       @Path("queryParam")
       @Produces("text/plain")
       String getQueryParam(@QueryParam("param")String param);

       @GET
       @Path("matrixParam")
       @Produces("text/plain")
       String getMatrixParam(@MatrixParam("param")String param);

       @GET
       @Path("uriParam/{param}")
       @Produces("text/plain")
       int getUriParam(@PathParam("param")int param);
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());

        ClientExecutor executor = new InMemoryClientExecutor() {
            @Override
            protected BaseClientResponse<?> createResponse(ClientRequest request, MockHttpResponse mockResponse) {
                try {                    
                    System.out.println("Client requesting " + request.getHttpMethod() + " on " + request.getUri());
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                mockResponse.setStatus(Status.OK.getStatusCode());
                return super.createResponse(request, mockResponse);
            }
        };

        SimpleClient client = ProxyFactory.create(SimpleClient.class, "http://localhost:8081", executor);
        client.putBasic("hello world");
    }
}
```