# RESTEasy InMemoryClient throws NPE with @FormParam

Tags: java, unit-testing, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using RESTEasy client framework version 2.3.5 (I am forced to use this but maybe I can upgrade to the newer version later) to create requests towards a DB server.
I googled a lot to know better how I should write good and clean unit tests for it.
I have found the InMemoryClientExecutor class which seems to fit my needs.

See this answer: [Is there a client-side mock framework for RESTEasy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631692/is-there-a-client-side-mock-framework-for-resteasy)

It works perfectly, but if I add a method to the client code (I have a same method with this same signature in the production code)

```
@POST
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public abstract HighLevelDeviceGateway testMethod(@FormParam("deviceGatewayName")   String param)
            throws Exception;
```

an NPE is thrown, this is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:120)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.testMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.mypackage.InMemoryClientExecutorExample.main(InMemoryClientExecutorExample.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.resteasy.mock.MockHttpRequest.getFormParameters(MockHttpRequest.java:259)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.InMemoryClientExecutor.loadHttpMethod(InMemoryClientExecutor.java:147)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.InMemoryClientExecutor.execute(InMemoryClientExecutor.java:75)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:39)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.execute(AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor.java:40)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientExecutionContextImpl.proceed(ClientExecutionContextImpl.java:45)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.execute(ClientRequest.java:443)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.httpMethod(ClientRequest.java:677)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:111)
... 3 more
```

It seems for me it's a bug, I tried with the latest version of RESTEasy, NPE is still there but the new version deprecates the Executor, though.

Some more info, this is the line where the NPE cames from:

```
if (getHttpHeaders().getMediaType().isCompatible(MediaType.valueOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")))
```

HTTP headers is not null but the media type is, I don't understand why..

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the first NPE by adding a "Content-Type" header to your request:

```
_request.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
```

However, this will not resolve the your issue.

The underlying problem is that the `InMemoryClientExecutor` incorrectly calls

```
mockHttpRequest.getFormParameters().add(key, value);
```

to add the from values instead of calling

```
mockHttpRequest.addFormHeader(key, value);
```

Because the formParameters collection starts out as null, calling `getFormParameters()` results in an attempt to parse the input stream which is empty.

It looks like `addFormHeader` is meant to both set the content type ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") and the form name/value pair to the decoded form parameter collection.

Sadly, as the whole `ClientExecutionContextImpl`and `ClientRequest` branch of the code seems to be marked as deprecated, I doubt that any of this will be fixed.  I hope we get some in-proc way to test the dispatch to resources. :S

For now, you can simply build a MultivalueMap collection with your form parameters and set it as the request body:

```
_request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE, _formData);
```

This will allow you to "send" form data :)

Comment: There is also the "easy" solution to simply extend the `InMemoryClientExecutor`, override the `loadHttpMethod` method, copying all the original code in it and replace `mockHttpRequest.getFormParameters().add(key, value);` with `mockHttpRequest.addFormHeader(key, value);`.